# Can someone explain this proof on aspherical manifolds?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, manifolds, fundamental-group

I am trying to understand this proof that the fundamental group of an aspherical manifold is torsion free. The proof is lemma 4.1 from [Aspherical manifolds](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Aspherical_manifolds#Non-aspherical_closed_manifolds) at the [Manifold Atlas Project](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Main_Page). The proof is:

Let $C\subseteq \pi_1(X)$ be a finite cyclic subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$. We have to show that $C$ is trivial. Since $X$ is aspherical, $C\backslash \widetilde X$ is a finite-dimensional model for $BC$. Hence $H_k(BC)=0$ for large $k$. This implies that $C$ is trivial.

What does "$C\backslash \widetilde X$" mean? I thought this might be a typo and they intended to take the quotient of the covering space over $C$. What is a model of a classifying space? Is this just a space homotopically equivalent to it? Why does the triviality of higher homology groups force $C$ to be trivial?

Comment: In a less fancy language: if you look at the covering space of $X$ that corresponds to a nontrivial finite cyclic subgroup $C$ you get an aspherical manifold $Y$ with fundamental group $C$. The group cohomology of $C$ and the cohomology of $Y$ are isomorphic, but the latter vanishes above the dimension of $Y$, while the former is known to be nontrivial in infinitely many dimensions, as proved e.g. in Brown's book "Cohomology of groups".

Comment: If $C \cong \mathbb{Z}_k$, then the infinite lens space $S^{\infty}/\mathbb{Z}_k$ is a model for $BC = B\mathbb{Z}_k$. You can use the standard CW decomposition to show that $H^i(B\mathbb{Z}_k; \mathbb{Z}_k) \cong \mathbb{Z}_k$ for every $i > 0$. See Example $2.43$ of Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) for details.

Comment: Just to connect what Igor said to the notation, I'm pretty sure $\widetilde{X}$ is supposed to be the universal cover, so $G \backslash \widetilde{X}$ is the covering space of $X$ corresponding to $G$ for any subgroup $G$ of $\pi_1(X)$

Comment: What does it mean precisely for $S^\infty / \mathbb{Z}_k$ to be a model of $B\mathbb{Z}_k$?

Comment: Any quotient of (nice) free action of a group $G$ on a contractible space is a "model" of $BG$.  When we say a space $X$ is a model of $BG$ it means that we can take $BG$ to be $X$ (there is no "unique choice" of $BG$).